# LUP разложение матриц python

Tags: python, математика, numpy, линейная-алгебра

Пытаюсь сделать LUP разложение с перестановками по столбцам. Матрицы P и L получилось посчитать, а вот с U возникли проблемы. Согласно учебнику оно определяется так:
[image: lup разложение]

Вот код:

```
def diy_lu_pivot(a):
    """
    Construct the LU decomposition of the input matrix.

    LU decomposition with column pivoting.
    """
    N = a.shape[0]
    U = a.copy()
    u = a.copy()
    L = np.eye(N)
    piv = np.arange(0,N)
    P = np.eye(N)
    lam = np.eye(N)
    for j in range(N-1):
        # Pivoting
        max_index = np.argmax(abs(u[j:N,j]))+j
        piv[[j,max_index]] = piv[[max_index,j]]
        u[:,0] = u[:,max_index]
        P[:,0] = P[:, max_index]
        gamma = u[j+1:, j] / u[j, j]
        lam[j+1:, j] = -gamma
        lam[j+1:, j] = gamma         
        U = lam@P@u
        L = L @ lam       
    return P,L,U
```

Матрица U никак не получается верхнетреугольной.

Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь!

Comment: Не хотите воспользоваться [готовой функцией](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html) ? ;)

Comment: Про нее знаю, но не могу, так как нужно именно реализовать самостоятельно.